# Tailwindcss not rendering in ExpressJS/React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, tailwind-css

I am trying to add TailwindCSS to my existing Express JS + React application. I have tried many different tutorials, such as this one https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation for regular JS, and this one made specifically for Create-React-App https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/create-react-app . I later tried this tutorial for express js https://daily.dev/blog/how-to-use-tailwindcss-with-node-js-express-and-pug
My project was initially made with Create-React-App, but I later changed everything to run in Express JS. So I need to build it first before I see any changes. I've done that every single time I try something different. I've even run the tailwind specific build command every time to see if that does anything but so far nothing. It seems like it doesn't even render on my plain html page, nevermind my react side.

Here is my project for reference https://github.com/twbluenaxela/LVChineseBusinessCrawler/pull/35

Here is my scripts for package json

```
"scripts": {
"predeploy": "npm install",
"dev": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider start",
"clientbuild": "npm install && node server/index.js",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"build": "react-scripts --openssl-legacy-provider build",
"build:css": "postcss src/index.css -o dist/output.css",
"eject": "react-scripts eject",
"start_cors": "node cors.js",
"start": "node server/index.js" }
```

Here's my post css config js

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [require('tailwindcss'), require('autoprefixer')],
}
```

Here's my tailwind config

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
      "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "./build/**/*.html"
    ],
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
      {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      },
    ],
  };
```

Here's my link to my dist folder in my index html (location: public/index.html)

```
    <link href="/dist/output.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Here's my express side. I think it possibly may have to deal with express first loading these 'chunk' files generated by running the 'react-scripts build' script and then defaulting to that rather than tailwind?

```
// Have Node serve the files for our built React app
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')));
//this is for tailwind.
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));


// Stop browser from sending requests to get the icon
app.get('../build/favicon.ico', (req, res) => res.status(204).end());

// All other GET requests not handled before will return our React app
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build/index.html'));
});

// Start the server and listen on the preconfigured port
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`App started on port ${port}.`));
```

Here's the log I get from the server when I reload the page

```
gitpod /workspace/LVChineseBusinessCrawler (NodemonFix) $ npm run start

> pachong@0.1.0 start
> node server/index.js

App started on port 3001.
GET / 200 3.406 ms - 2371
GET /dist/output.css 200 1.897 ms - 2371
GET /static/css/main.a6b1053c.chunk.css 200 0.556 ms - 108
GET /static/js/2.b2955d3e.chunk.js 200 0.561 ms - 188544
GET /static/js/main.bfafc08b.chunk.js 200 0.453 ms - 2862
GET /static/css/main.a6b1053c.chunk.css.map 200 0.609 ms - 227
GET /favicon.ico 200 0.719 ms - 3870
GET /manifest.json 200 0.401 ms - 319
```

As you can see it does seem like it knows where my output.css is and I'm assuming it loads it? So maybe its' the chunk css overwriting it?
So I tested it on my index html in my public folder by changing the h1 heading to this line

```
    <h1 class="text-3xl font-bold underline">
```

And it just shows regular h1 without any underline or anything.
Is there something I'm not seeing here? I would realllyyy appreciate any help I could get!!

edit1:
Here's my index.css as well

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this [link](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/02/tailwindcss-react-project/).

It has the detailed possible explanation of setting up tailwind for react

Follow all the steps carefully. And make sure it is working fine and then add the `express` module

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you so much! This fixed it. So the issue was that, in my index.js I was importing the initial index.css file which only included the tailwind directives. Then I tried importing my generated tailwind css file (located at dist/output.css) and it didnt work. However when I put my generated dist folder into my src folder, then imported that file into my index.js, it started to work. Thank you!

Comment: I'm happy to hear that, as you are a new user , if you appreciate any of the below answers make sure you up vote and the answer which worked , mark it as tick . Which will help others to quickly find the useful answer

Comment: I can't upvote yet but I marked your answer with the green checkmark. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies on the `/build` folder and your `tailwind.config.js` file not reading the files it's supposed to read.

You're supposed to watch for any class used in your `/build` folder files, especially any `html`/`pug` file.

Also tailwind is not told to watch the `/public` folder, that is why the underline style was not showing up.

Try this `tailwind.config.js` file.

```
module.exports = {
    content: [
      "./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
      "./build/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,pug,html}"
    ],
    theme: {
      extend: {},
    },
    plugins: [
      {
        tailwindcss: {},
        autoprefixer: {},
      },
    ],
  };
```

If you want Tailwind to watch `/public` too, just add `"./public/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,pug,html}"` on the `content` array. *Not recommended though*.

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to reply!! So here's what I did. I changed my tailwind.config.js file to include what you have up there. Then I ran npm install, npm ci, npm run build:css (executes this line: postcss src/index.css -o dist/output.css), then I ran npm run build, and finally npm start. Still nothing has changed... I even tried linking the public folder by adding "./public/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,pug,html}" but it doesnt seem to have helped... is there another why i can debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the following in the `index.css` file

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Comment: Hi there! Yes I have 

Comment: Try to restart the server

Comment: Hey thanks for replying, I have run npm run build, npm ci, and then npm start in that order everytime I tried something different.